# How to open and login to calendar app which is opened by my Application ?

Tags: android, xamarin, automated-tests

My application is adding event to calendar. So, every time my script open a calendar app through my application. But issue is to use calendar I need to login with google account. 
So, I am stuck at this point. How can I login into calendar app through my script and come back to my application ?